# How to switch off filtering for a certain column in Kendo grid after it's loaded?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid created with the usual MVC Razor syntax.

For example,

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<exampleViewModel>()
    .Name("ExampleGridName")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("ExampleMethod", "ExampleClass"))
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(m => m.Id);
        c.Bound(m => m.FirstName);
        c.Bound(m => m.LastName);
    });
    .Filterable())
```

My question: Is there a way to switch off filtering for a column like "LastName" after the grid is loaded using jquery?

I was successful iterating through the columns and identify the one I need filtering switched off. I tried setting the filterable property to false but it didn't work. Maybe because it looks like an object type.

I came across this issue as I was trying to reuse a grid but had to apply different filters during load for the pages. The filters worked but when the filter was cleared, the grid was totally reset. When I have the filter switched off at run time, the reset would reset but keep the filters applied during load.

Comment: If you don't want filtering on the bound column you can just add  c.Bound(m => m.FirstName).Filterable(false) and that will turn filtering off for the column only but leave filtering on for everything else.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I am also using the grid on other pages and they prefer that it have filter on the column for those other pages.

Comment: @DavidShorthose To be more detailed. The grid is in a partial page and I have a metric table with counts that represents items from these kendo grid. When the metric is selected the kendo grid read from the full dataSource and is filtered accordingly using jquery. In order to lock the filter that represent the metric I would like to switch it off. The alternative would be creating new kendo grid with a different dataSource(new Method, Parameter) retrieve from the DB, but that can lead to a large combination of kendo grid and dataSource.

Comment: check out this dojo I created based of Telerik's own filter grid demo and let me know if this is along the right track for you http://dojo.telerik.com/ogAYO

Comment: just to be clear it removes the filter link from the City column. which was added when the grid was initialized.

Comment: @DavidShorthose. Thanks. I was looking to see if there was some kendo grid property that I might have missed but this will do. I had to change th[role="columnheader"] to class = "k-header" to make it work. Maybe because of different kendo version. You should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this dojo I created based of Telerik's own filter grid demo and let me know if this is along the right track for you [filter demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ogAYO)

code that I added to the demo.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var preventFilter = 'City'

  console.log($('th[role="columnheader"]').length);
  $('th[role="columnheader"]').filter('[data-role="filtermenu"]').each(function (item) {


      if ($(this).attr("data-field") == preventFilter) {
          console.log('matched')
          $(this).attr("data-role", "");
          $(this).find("a").remove();
          $(this).removeClass('k-filterable');
      }

  });
```

});
just to be clear it removes the filter link from the City column. which was added when the grid was initialized.

This works based on the filter item being in the header if you have either the menu or the row features enabled then you will need to change the code appropriately.

Glad this helped.